Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted wasor may be using frozencache with a missing file. \end{mintedbox}
I'm stuck in this error message:
(the original code is from
How to present a Python code snippet efficiently in LaTeX?)
Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted wasor may be using frozencache with a missing file. \end{mintedbox} 

I have already install pygments using: pip install Pygments
This is the latex code: (I invoked LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag. )
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{minted}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,breakable,xparse,skins}
\definecolor{bg}{gray}{0.95}
\DeclareTCBListing{mintedbox}{O{}m!O{}}{%
    breakable=true,
    listing engine=minted,
    listing only,
    minted language=#2,
    minted style=default,
    minted options={%
        linenos,
        gobble=0,
        breaklines=true,
        breakafter=,,
        fontsize=\small,
        numbersep=8pt,
        #1},
    boxsep=0pt,
    left skip=0pt,
    right skip=0pt,
    left=25pt,
    right=0pt,
    top=3pt,
    bottom=3pt,
    arc=5pt,
    leftrule=0pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    bottomrule=2pt,
    toprule=2pt,
    colback=bg,
    colframe=orange!70,
    enhanced,
    overlay={%
        \begin{tcbclipinterior}
            \fill[orange!20!white] (frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=20pt]frame.north west);
    \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    #3}
\begin{document}
    \begin{mintedbox}{python}
        if transactions: Transaction.create_transactions() # if transactions = "true"
        node.generate_emptyState() # empty state for all nodes
        S.initial_events() # initiate initial events to start with
        
        while not queue.isEmpty() and clock <= targetTime:
        next_e = queue.get_next_event()
        clock = next_e.time # move clock to the time of the event
        Event.execute_event(next_e)
        Queue.remove_event(next_e)
        
        print results
    \end{mintedbox}
    
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SX! Please note, that TeX.SX uses Markdown not HTML. HTML is usually filtered and does not have the result you'd expect, i.e. for code. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

How do you compile your document? Via an editor?

I'm using texstudio.I added a command with: user:graphviz-pdflatex and the command txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]
and I compile with that

Can you check in the texstudio preferences->Build->Commands ($PATH) if this field contains the path to your python?

1.Check if you use -shell-escape to compile your file
eg:
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape

2.Put your python in computer path

Enter in cmd, If you use anaconda install python, Enter in anaconda prompt
where python




Put the file path in the path



minted 3.0.0 or newer does no longer require shell-escape
